# Как скрыть/показать окно используя горячие клавиши?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, клавиатура, pynput

Не получается реализовать демонстрацию окна по горячим клавишам.
Хочу добиться следующего: окно было свернуто, по нажатию "горячих клавиш" окно переходит в состояние `show`.

Использую *PyQT* и библиотеку *keyboard* для перехватывания клавиатуры.
В отдельном потоке ожидаю нажатия клавиши (в данном случае  <kbd>Esc</kbd>), после чего демонстрирую окно.

Окно зависает и вылетает. Возможно, потому что я работаю с *GUI* из другого потока. 
Как можно решить задачу?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QSystemTrayIcon, QStyle
import keyboard
import threading


class ScreenArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 500)  # Устанавливаем размеры
        #self.show()


def show(w):
    while True:
        keyboard.wait('esc')
        w.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = ScreenArea()
threading.Thread(target=show, args=(w,)).start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: не используйте сниферы для реализации хоткеев. используйте хоткеи qt или os

Answer (score 0):

У меня нет библиотеки `keyboard`, но у меня есть библиотека `pynput`, которая предназначена для тех же целей.

Пример ниже рабочий, понажимайте клавиши `esc` и `space`.
Насколько это потокобезопасно? Думаю, нет.

Я добавил обработку некоторых событий: символ `c` и `C`; клавишу `alt_l`,
а также комбинацию клавиш (`Alt_l+c`, `Alt_l+C`, `Alt_r+c`, `Alt_r+C` ). Пробуйте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QSystemTrayIcon, QStyle

#import keyboard                
from pynput import keyboard      # pip install pynput
import threading

class ScreenArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 500)  
        self.show()

def show(w):
    # Ключевые комбинации для проверки
    COMBINATIONS = [
        {keyboard.Key.alt_l, keyboard.KeyCode(char='c')}, # Alt_l + c
        {keyboard.Key.alt_l, keyboard.KeyCode(char='C')}, # Alt_l + C
        {keyboard.Key.alt_r, keyboard.KeyCode(char='c')}, # Alt_r + c
        {keyboard.Key.alt_r, keyboard.KeyCode(char='C')}  # Alt_r + C
    ]

    # # текущий активный модификатор
    current = set()

    def executeAltC():
        print ("\n *** Нажата комбинация клавиш: Alt+C\n *** Сделайте что-нибудь :)") 

    def get_key_name(key):
        """ Функцию get_key_name(), будет проверять тип ключа. 
        Для нормального ключа он вернет key.char, 
        у которого не будет дополнительных одинарных кавычек. 
        Для других ключей он напечатает имя ключа (например, Key.cmd, Key.alt, Key.ctrl ...)
        """
        if isinstance(key, keyboard.KeyCode):
            return key.char
        else:
            return str(key)    

    def on_press(key):
        key_name = get_key_name(key)

        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            print('--- Нажата клавиша: {}'.format(key_name))
            w.hide()
        elif key == keyboard.Key.space:
            print('--- Нажата клавиша: {}'.format(key_name))
            w.show()
        elif key == keyboard.Key.alt_l:                      
            print('--- Нажата клавиша: {}'.format(key_name))  

        # KeyCode события нажатия символа    
        elif (key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('c')) or \
             (key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('C')):          
            print('--- Нажата клавиша: {}'.format(key_name))

        else:
            print('Информационно. Вы нажали: {}'.format(key_name))        
            current.clear() 

        # Клавиши-модификаторы. Alt_l+c, Alt_l+C, Alt_r+c, Alt_r+C 
        # any(iterable) -> bool. Проверяет, есть ли среди указанных элементов 
        # хотя бы один, принимающий значение `истина` 
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
                executeAltC()         
                current.clear()             

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = ScreenArea()
threading.Thread(target=show, args=(w, ), daemon=True).start() # + daemon=True
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Как не странно, делал тоже самое не keyboard и не работает. Использование библиотеки мне не принципиально) Не очень понимаю, как поймать события нажатия символа на клавиатуре? Скажем, пытаюсь поймать комбинацию alt+c. Alt ловлю без проблем (keyboard.Key.alt), а как поймать символ "с"?

Comment: @chessinvin я добавил код по интересующим вас вопросам. Пробуйте.